# arranging data by date (month/day format)

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, time-series, pandas-groupby

After I append 4 different dataframes in:

```
list_1 = [ ]
```

I have the following data stored in list_1:

```
| date       | 16/17 | 
| --------   | ------|
| 2016-12-29 | 50    | 
| 2016-12-30 | 52    | 
| 2017-01-01 | 53    | 
| 2017-01-02 | 51    |
[4 rows x 1 columns],
             16/17

| date       | 17/18 | 
| --------   | ------| 
| 2017-12-29 | 60    | 
| 2017-12-31 | 62    | 
| 2018-01-01 | 64    | 
| 2018-01-03 | 65    | 
[4 rows x 1 columns],
             17/18

| date       | 18/19 |
| --------   | ------| 
| 2018-12-30 | 54    | 
| 2018-12-31 | 53    | 
| 2019-01-02 | 52    | 
| 2019-01-03 | 51    | 
[4 rows x 1 columns],
             18/19

| date       | 19/20 |
| --------   | ------| 
| 2019-12-29 | 62    | 
| 2019-12-30 | 63    | 
| 2020-01-01 | 62    | 
| 2020-01-02 | 60    | 
[4 rows x 1 columns],
             19/20
```

For changing the date format to month/day I use the following code:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['date']).dt.strftime('%m/%d')
```

But the problem is when I want to arrange the data by months/days like that:

```
| date     | 16/17 | 17/18 | 18/19 | 19/20 |
| -------- | ------| ------| ------| ------|
| 12/29    | 50    | 60    | NaN   | 62    |
| 12/30    | 52    | NaN   | 54    | 63    |
| 12/31    | NaN   | 62    | 53    | NaN   |
| 01/01    | 53    | 64    | NaN   | 62    |
| 01/02    | 51    | NaN   | 52    | 60    |
| 01/03    | NaN   | 65    | 51    | NaN   |
```

I've tried the following:

```
df = pd.concat(list_1,axis=1)
```

also:

```
df = pd.concat(list_1)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['date']).first()
```

also:

```
df = pd.concat(list_1)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df = df.groupby(['date'] sort=False).first()
```

but still cannot achieve the desired result.

Comment: Are you trying to `pivot` your dataframe?

Comment: I am not sure for the pivot, Luke. I simply want to compare the data for the different years by month/day (hence month/day format), while preserving the date order (starting from 12/29 and ending 01/03 as in the example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `sort=False` in `groupby` and create new column for subtract by first value of `DatetimeIndex` and use it for sorting:

```
def f(x):
    x.index = pd.to_datetime(x.index)
    return x.assign(new =  x.index - x.index.min())

L = [x.pipe(f) for x in list_1]
df = pd.concat(L, axis=0).sort_values('new', kind='mergesort')

df = df.groupby(df.index.strftime('%m/%d'), sort=False).first().drop('new', axis=1)
print (df)
       16/17  17/18  18/19  19/20
date                             
12/29   50.0   60.0    NaN   62.0
12/30   52.0    NaN   54.0   63.0
12/31    NaN   62.0   53.0    NaN
01/01   53.0   64.0    NaN   62.0
01/02   51.0    NaN   52.0   60.0
01/03    NaN   65.0   51.0    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you jezrael for the suggestion! The problem when I try this, is that the new dataframe starts from 01/01 and not from 12/29 as desired. Is there any way to preserve the date order (to start from 12/29 and end 01/03 as in the example for the desired outcome)?

Comment: I've tried that one too. It preserves the order, but it groups the data by the first column (16/17) and rows like 12/31 (where the value for 16/17 is NaN) are moved down and don't stay in place. @jezrael

Comment: @kobo - Answer was edited.

Comment: That works perfect, thank you! And any tips if I have more months included? For example if the data starts from 09/30 and ends on 03/30, keeping the same logic. @jezrael